# Rails Image Upload to S3 with carrierwave and fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3, carrierwave, fog

Hello I've been developing a web application I and want to give users the possibility to upload profile pictures. I spent a lot of time trying to get carrierwave and fog working with s3 but have not managed to accomplish it. Any help you can give me is much apreciated.

Update:
Ive kept trying to fiddle around with it and from what i can tell the file is never uplaoding, the :image value is always empty in the Users controller.

My uploader class.

```
class PhotoUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
   storage :fog
   def store_dir
      "uploads/#images/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}"
   end
end
```

The fog initializer

```
CarrierWave.configure do |config| 
  config.fog_credentials = { 
    :provider               => 'AWS', 
    :aws_access_key_id      => 'xxx', 
    :aws_secret_access_key  => 'yyy', 
  } 
  config.fog_directory  = 'pictures_dev' 
  config.fog_public     = true
  config.fog_attributes = {'Cache-Control'=>'max-age=315576000'}
end
```

User model

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  ....
  has_one :photo
  ....
end
```

Photo Model

```
class Photo
include Mongoid::Document
attr_accessible :name, :image

field :image, :type => String
field :name, :type => String

belongs_to :user

mount_uploader :image, PhotoUploader
 end
```

Photo Controller

```
  class PhotoController < ApplicationController

    def update
    @photo = Photo.find(params[:id])
      if @photo.update_attributes(params[:image]) 
        flash[:success] = "Your have updated your settings successfully."
      else
        flash[:error] = "Sorry! We are unable to update your settings. Please check your      fields and try again."
    end
    redirect_to(:back)
   end
```

Upload form

```
= form_for @photo, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f|
  %p
    %label Photo
    = image_tag(@user.image_url) if @photo.image? 
    = f.file_field :image
    = f.submit
```

This is all I can think of that is relevant, if anyone need me to post more code I'll be happy to. 
I am honestly stumped and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is there any errors in your logs?

Comment: You might have placed your S3 buckets in the wrong region?

Comment: Christopher, the S3 bucket is in the correct region. Kyle, no errors whatsoever. The image simply never gets uploaded.

Comment: Have you tried putting a debugger statement directly after @photo = Photo.find(params[:id]) then from the debugger starting irb and trying to do it manually? You might find the problem that way.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure out the issue for anyone interested. It was the fact that I was using devise with my user and there needed to be some different configuration in the upload forms in order for it to work correctly. Here is the link to the documentation that helped me in case there are others with the issue.

https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to%3A-use-carrierwave-with-devise

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a problem with

```
if @photo.update_attributes(params[:image])
```

try something like this instead

```
if @photo.update_attributes(image: params[:photo][:image])
```